# Flash plugin crashes frequently

Tags: macos, plugins, adobe-flash

In various websites, at random times and with no apparent pattern, the Flash plugin will crash. This has occurred in every browser, and I typically have at least one crash a day. According to Mozilla's [plugin check](http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/plugincheck/) I have the latest version of Flash (10.1.102.64)

This is a new MacBook Pro (17", 2010 unibody version) running fully updated Mac OS X 10.6.5.

Does the plugin just crash for everyone, or is this unique to me? How often does Flash crash for you? Is there anything I can check, or is there a way I can reinstall Flash or some other diagnosis I can run? I haven't been experiencing other issues with my computer or my browser.

Comment: When I'm using it for something, it crashes for me at least once a day.  Even when it works, it's usually pretty slow.  That's why I use FlashBlock.  None of the websites that I use need it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's a reason why Apple appears to onlookers to be so anti-Flash, and it's because Flash sucks on Macs (it may also suck on other OSs, but I don't use them enough to be knowledgeable).

What to do about it depends on what browser you use (your question doesn't say, as Mozilla's Plugin Check isn't FF-only):

- **Safari** - the answer is [ClickToFlash](http://clicktoflash.com). Honestly, C2F is something that should just come pre-installed on every Mac.
- **Firefox/Camino** - As Ken mentioned in a comment, you want the [FlashBlock](http://flashblock.mozdev.org/) extension.
- **Chrome** - use the [FlashBlock for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/gofhjkjmkpinhpoiabjplobcaignabnl) extension.

As has already been said: you can get along fine on almost all sites without Flash. Here's some additional recommended reading, both of which are from John Gruber at [Daring Fireball](http://daringfireball.net):

- [Going Flash-Free on Mac OS X, and How to Cheat When You Need It](http://daringfireball.net/2010/11/flash_free_and_cheating_with_google_chrome)
- [Masquerading as Mobile Safari to Get Websites to Serve HTML5 Video to Safari on Mac OS X](http://daringfireball.net/2010/11/masquerading_as_mobile_safari)

Comment: +1 for Going Flash-Free. I’ve done that and I love it. When I see the missing plug-in I laugh. Sometimes when I have to, there’s always chrome :)

Comment: Great suggestion, I don't know why I didn't think of this before! I installed FlashBlock (I'm a Firefox user) and it's simply awesome. This is a great "solution" to the Flash problem.

Answer (score 5):

Flash on the Mac is the single-largest cause of Safari crashes. That's just the way it is.

Comment: Indeed. I would just add that you should simply uninstall flash and if a site uses it, write to the author and complain.

Answer (score 2):

Flash crashed so often for me, I have [gone flash free and only use flash in Google Chrome browser](http://daringfireball.net/2010/11/flash_free_and_cheating_with_google_chrome). Google installs flash within that one app, updates flash behind the scenes and Safari hasn't crashed once in 6 months.

I would recommend three useful and stable Safari extensions if you disable flash in Safari:

- YouTube5
- HTML5 Audio
- H.264 Flickr Video

[image: Safari Extensions]

Answer (score 1):

I recently found [FlashVideoReplacer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/flashvideoreplacer/) for Firefox.  It replaces Flash videos with native players like Quicktime when available.  Flash is a CPU killer for me, so this helps.